# Scrolling a TextView to a specific line

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I have a TextView inside a ScrollView. Let's say the ScrollView is named `s` and the TextView is named `t`.

I have many lines to be displayed in the TextView and at the same time I want to scroll the view to a specific line.

So I did this:

```
t.setText(aVeryLongString);
int y = t.getLayout().getLineTop(40); // e.g. I want to scroll to line 40
s.scrollTo(0, y);
```

But it won't scroll, **except** the second time. It seems that on the first time the code finishes, the ScrollView knows how much the total height of the TextView is.

So I think there must be something to force calculating the needed height before the scrollTo call. How to do that (or otherwise)?

Comment: Are you running the code in the UI thread?

Comment: It's the code at onReceiveResult (called another activity, the activity put some data and finish(), and received the data). I don't understand enough about the threading model in android.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/59b6cc97206d2f8d).

Instead of calling `scrollTo` directly, we must call `post` instead on the ScrollView. This works.

```
t.setText(aVeryLongString);
s.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int y = t.getLayout().getLineTop(40); // e.g. I want to scroll to line 40
        s.scrollTo(0, y);
    }
});
```

Comment: Almost 2 years later.. I thought this was the same as posting the code to a handler. It turns out that you need to post it to the scrollview instead of to the handler. (the above code is correct)