# Scroll to searched text and bringing it on top of the textview

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I have a search option where user can search word from the given textview. An example of a [sample TextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enCsS.png)
and if user searches for "cupY cup  n" then the text in the blue box should be scrolled to the top to [first line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj9Xh.png).

I have tried the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945477/scrolling-a-textview-to-a-specific-line) here but I don't know how to find the line number of the searched text.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? I cannot understand exactly what you want. What I understand is that you have either a ListView or RecyclerView and you want to filter its results based on the typed text in a InputText (i.e.). In order to achieve this you can do:

1. Add a textChangeListener to your InputText (reference http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html);
2. At the end of this listener, filter the list and pass the filtered list to its adapter, then call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I am sorry but I have a edittext and search button in one activity and textview in the next activity. When the search text is entered in the edittext and search button is pressed, I want that text to be shown at the top of the textview when it goes to the next activity (as shown in the image above). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Okay, now it does. Just pass the typed text as an extra into the intent to the next activity. On the method onCreate of the next activity fetch the extra passed and set you TextView with a text starting with the retrieved text

Comment: Yea, but I want the text above the searched text to be visible, too. Basically, I want ScrollView to auto scroll to that searched text.

Comment: if you're using a ScrollView with TextViews inside a layout manager that acts as a child for the ScrollView, use the method scrollTo from ScrollVIew after recovering its instance. I would say that this is easier to do with a ListView