# Scrolling a specific line of textview to top not working for last screen-full

Tags: java, scrollto

I intend that the following code scroll the `textview` so that the line with the
found token becomes the top line. I based my code on this SO question ...
[Scrolling a TextView to a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945477/scrolling-a-textview-to-a-specific-line)

It works except when the last screen-full is displayed, that is, when manual
scrolling by the user will not scroll the text either. I expect that this
behavior has to do with how `getLineForOffset`, `getLineTop` and especially `scrollTo` work together, but i do not understand this well enough to determine what to do  about it. There are a few other SO questions on this same topic of scrolling to   a specific line but i do not see this particular issue addressed.

iFind is initialized to 0 for the first find.

```
case R.id.findnext:
    tokenString = token.getText().toString();
    iFind = containsIgnoreCase(tokenString, html.getText().toString(), ++iFind);
    if (iFind == -1) toast("Not Found: " + tokenString);
    else {
        final Layout lay = html.getLayout();
        final int lineNumb = lay.getLineForOffset(iFind);
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int y = lay.getLineTop(lineNumb);
                mScrollView.scrollTo(0, y);
            }
        });
    }
    public int containsIgnoreCase(String needle, String hayStack, int start) {
       final int lengthNeedle = needle.length();
       final char firstLo = Character.toLowerCase(needle.charAt(0));
       final char firstUp = Character.toUpperCase(needle.charAt(0));

       int i;
       for (i = start;  i < hayStack.length() - lengthNeedle; i++) {
           final char ch = hayStack.charAt(i);
           if (ch != firstLo && ch != firstUp)
               continue;
           if (hayStack.regionMatches(true, i, needle, 0, lengthNeedle))
               return i;
       }
       return -1;
   }

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/codeHTML"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background_material_light"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading my post, especially the phrase "*when manual scrolling by the user will not scroll the text either*", I realized that `scrollTo` quite simply will not do this. Instead i am using `Spannable` to highlight the found token so that the line need not be at the top of the TextView. This is much better for the user who will now instantly see the line containing the token, and its context.