# Android TextView insert Text to the Start Scrolls the Text View to the very begining

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to display the pages of a book. For this, I am using a  single TextView. As user scrolls down and reaches the bottom I append new text to the existing TextView. the user can continue reading the text without any hindrance.

I am trying to do the same while the user scrolls up. As user reaches the start portion of the text which he read earlier, I am trying to add some texts to the start.

For Example, Say I have 100 lines of text to display. I am displaying only 20 lines on the first instance. So when the user opened the app I displayed lines 41 - 60. Now when the user reaches line 60 I add lines 61-80 to the screen. I do that using this line,

```
txt_MyText.append(getResources().getString(R.string.dummy_text1));
```

Now say if the user scrolls up and reaches line 41, I want to display lines 21 - 40. For this, I am using this piece of code,

```
txt_MyText.getEditableText().insert(0, getResources().getString(R.string.dummy_text0));
```

This works fine, but after adding the text the TextView resets its position to the very start. I do not want to TextView to automatically scroll up to the top.

How can I achieve that?

Here is my layout,

```
<com.abc.book.utils.NesterScrollView
    android:id="@+id/readerScroll"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
             >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_MyText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:text="@string/dummy_text"/>

</com.abc.book.utils.NesterScrollView>
```

Also within code, I initialize the textView like this,

```
txt_MyText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

How to fix my issue, when I add text to the end it's not scrolling but only when I add to the start. How prevent that scrolling when text is inserted at the start?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your code is that you append the lines everytime the user reaches the end, however you do not delete the old text. 
So that means that you do not want to insert the text again when the user returns to the previous "page". Else there will be duplicates.
You are also inserting at 0, which means that it will insert at the very beginning.

What you can do is jump to a specific line. I advise trying an approach similar to this: [Scrolling a TextView to a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945477/scrolling-a-textview-to-a-specific-line)